# Shell script to take up daily DB backup (for something like Redmine, etc)

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, backup, redmine

Need a script solution to take daily back-up of a DB and send a mail for it.

The code makes a back-up for mysql DB and the files involved (as in most use cases)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a blog nor a site to dump code to. While self-answered questions are fine in principal, please stick to the questions-answer format. That is, your question should stand on its own and describe a specific question for a piece of code you are writing. Your question is a typical "give me teh codez" question which normally would be rather quickly closed.

Comment: @Holger Just: Thanks for letting me know. I have come to stackoverflow for such kinds of questions and love it when I find solutions. I understand it's not a code to copy site but I am sure many of us use stackoverflow for that too.
But be assure I will not be using this site for posting my such codes anymore. Can you suggest a place? I want to help people too and make it visible to a large audience seeking answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cat /dev/null > Body.text
DATE=`date +%b/%d/%Y`
BACKUP_DIR="/home/user/Redmine/tmp"
DB_NAME="xxx"
DB_USER="xxx"
DB_PASSWORD="XXXXXX"
Redmine_Root="/home/webuser/apps/redmine"
echo "Redmine Backup Directory is $BACKUP_DIR" >> /root/Body.text
rm -rf $BACKUP_DIR/files* $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine*

# -- MySQL
echo "`date` at Redmine's MySQL db Backup on" >> /root/Body.text
mysqldump -u $DB_USER  -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_NAME > $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine.sql
gzip $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine.sql
rm -f $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine.sql

#........Redmine
echo "`date` at REDMINE_Files Backup " >> /root/Body.text

#Create back up for Files
echo "Backing up Redmine attachments..." 
rsync -a $Redmine_Root/files/ $BACKUP_DIR/files/

echo "Packing into single archive redmine files" 
tar -zcvf $BACKUP_DIR/redminefiles.tar $BACKUP_DIR/files
rm -rf $BACKUP_DIR/files/

#Create a single tar file
echo "Create Backup of Single File" >> /root/Body.text
cd /home/user/Redmine
tar -cvf Redmine`date +%b%d%y`.tar tmp/
tar -cvf /home/user/Redmine`date +%d%b%y`.tar /home/user/Redmine/tmp
rm -f $BACKUP_DIR/redminefiles* $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine*
rm -f $BACKUP_DIR/Redmine.sql.gz

#Cleaning Up
echo "Delete five days olderbackup" >> /root/Body.text
find /home/maitreya/Redmine/* -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;

#Sending Report
/usr/bin/mutt -e "set realname=\" Redmine-Backup\"  "   \  -s "Redmine Backup on $DATE" xy@yz.com -c yz@xy.com < /root/Body.text
```

Comment: can you tell me about this `Body.text` what it does?. I am not getting why it is being used?